# 'search keyword' embedded URL using &q=

Tags: python, url, search, lxml, keyword

I would like to make a 'search keyword' embedded URL using &q=, like

http://www.website.com/&q='search keyword'
(search keywords will be chosen from mysql table)

then, scrape download or get the image url links of images on the result page using lxml .xpath

Can I make this automation in Python?

This is not a google api, and just for practice purpose.

Best,

Comment: ya, try `requests.get('http://www.website.com/&q=' + keyword)`

Comment: Thanks, actually I would like to know the syntax of adding a keyword (selected from mysql) to URL, then run imagescraper in python to download images from the webpage, then store those images into mysql.